# MatLab block transpose

Tags: matlab

This is a tab-delimited txt that looks like

```
A  2000  a  B  2001  b  C  1999 c
X  2005  x  Y  1995  y
```

There will be hundreds of rows like these.

I want to create matrices like

```
mat1 = [A  2000  a ; B  2001  b ; C  1999 c]

mat2 = [X  2005  x ; Y  1995  y]
```

I think this is doable if I just use for and if and so on.

But I am not sure if I can do it by some more efficient matlab command using block transpose.

Comment: matrices contain same type of elements, so they cannot have both `A` and `2000` . Have you considered cells , if then what format you would need for cells

Comment: @Nishant A, B.. these will be numbers

Comment: the lines in the text file have same number of entries or different ?

Comment: @Nishant Some entries are either empty, NaN. But if it is necessary, I can replace them with things like 99999.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
id = fopen('input.txt');
tline = fgetl(id);
ii  = 1;
while ischar(tline)
cell_{ii} = cellfun(@(x)(str2double(x)),reshape(regexp(tline,'\t','split')',3,[])');
ii = ii+1;
tline = fgetl(id);
end
fclose(id);
```

The output matrices are stored in the cell array , `cell_`

input file  is

```
564 564 5646    65466   458 545
785 878 8745    555 547 5665    55966   66588   6654
```

output is

```
 cell_{1}

 ans =

     564         564        5646
   65466         458         545

cell_{2}

ans =

     785         878        8745
     555         547        5665
   55966       66588        6654
```

Comment: ?? Shouldn't cell_{1} be [564 564 5646; 65466   458 545] and cell_{2} be [785 878 8745 ; 555 547 5665 ; 55966   66588   6654]

Comment: Does this code take the fact that the input is tab-delimited? From several error messages like "Error using reshape
Product of known dimensions, 3, not divisible into total
number of elements, 28."  I guess this code isn't for tab-delimited input?

Comment: @user3123767 I have changed it , can you try it now and notify me of any error,

Comment: fgets changed to fgetl. I will try. Still I get the same error message.

Comment: @user3123767 Can I see you text file , so that I could rat out the bugs

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1sEqo7wNB1-QUtGdEJsdWQ5N1U/edit?usp=sharing This is the txt file I am testing with. Is there any problem with this file?

Comment: Another seemingly-more-easy-to-deal-with file is this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1sEqo7wNB1-WDB2bi1fTkhwR0k/edit?usp=sharing  This can be imported as matrix.

Comment: @user3123767 I downloaded both of these files, executed my answer and got the desired results without any error or warning . I am using matlab r2013a , which version are you using

Comment: R2012a. And https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1sEqo7wNB1-TEdBRnk2RlJ5WTA/edit?usp=sharing this is strsplit.m that I downloaded to my C:\Users\....\MATLAB directory.  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1sEqo7wNB1-UjBtdFVocjVtWTA/edit?usp=sharing this is mfile I ran. And the error message says "No delimiter in string, inputString is returned
Error using reshape
Product of known dimensions, 3, not divisible into total
number of elements, 26.

Error in aa_block_transpose (line 5)
cell_{ii} =
cellfun(@(x)(str2double(x)),reshape(strsplit(tline,'\t')',3,[])'); "

Comment: @user3123767 try this , I have removed `strsplit` and added `regexp` which is supported in r2012. Notify me for any errors.

Comment: This worked! I could also study and understand functions in your code. Thank you. Lastly, vertcat(cell_{1},cell_{2}) fails because they have different length. How can I vertically integrate "cell_{}"s and export to txt?